# KendoUI grid optimize

Tags: jquery, optimization, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two kendo Grid named:

```
var sourcegrid = $('#usersGrid').data("kendoGrid");        //SOURCE GRID
var destinationgrid = $('#teamGrid').data('kendoGrid');    //DESTINATION GRID
```

In sourcegrid i have 1000 records and in destinationgrid has no records.

I have button that transfer data from sourcegrid  to destinationgrid.

Code:

```
 sourcegrid.select().each(function () {
        var dataItem = sourcegrid.dataItem($(this));
        destinationgrid.dataSource.add(dataItem);
        sourcegrid.removeRow($(this));
    });
```

When Im transferring 500 records to destinationgrid. the process of transferring is so
slow. Any idea to optimize it.

Thanks

you can edit this 
   http://jsfiddle.net/2qXKy/112/

Comment: Probably this is better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to speed things up for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/5t5c2g1y/2/

```
var ds1 = new kendo.data.DataSource( {
    data: createRandomData(500),
    scrollable: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                id: {
                    type: 'number',
                    editable: true
                },
                FirstName: {
                    type: 'string',
                    editable: true
                },
                LastName: {
                    type: 'string',
                    editable: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

var ds2 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: createRandomData(0),
    scrollable: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                id: {
                    type: 'number',
                    editable: true
                },
                FirstName: {
                    type: 'string',
                    editable: true
                },
                LastName: {
                    type: 'string',
                    editable: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

var sourcegrid = $("#usersGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds1,
    editable: "popup",
    selectable: "multiple",
    pageable: false,
    columns: [{
        field: "FirstName",
        width: 90,
        title: "First Name"
    }, {
        field: "LastName",
        width: 90,
        title: "Last Name"
    }]
}).data("kendoGrid");

var destinationgrid = $("#teamGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds2,
    editable: "popup",
    selectable: "multiple",
    pageable: false,
    columns: [{
        field: "FirstName",
        width: 90,
        title: "First Name"
    }, {
        field: "LastName",
        width: 90,
        title: "Last Name"
    }]
}).data("kendoGrid");


$('input[type=button]').on('click',function() {
    var removalList = []; 
    sourcegrid.select().each(function () {

        var dataItem = sourcegrid.dataItem($(this));
        console.log(dataItem);
        removalList.push(dataItem)
        ds2.add(dataItem);


    });

   for(var i = 0; i< removalList.length;i++)
   {
       ds1.remove(removalList[i]);
   }

});
```

If you interact with the datasources rather than the grids themselves you will hopefully see the process is a lot quicker (plus gets rid of the pop up message asking you to confirm the removal)

You will notice that I have added a console statement just so you can see the information being copied across.

Again hope this helps.

Comment: thanks David Shorthose. another issue when selecting all records and pass it to destinationgrid. it hang/stopped .like how many seconds to respond

Comment: Well it depends on the speed of your machine I guess. You could add a note to the screen/ progress bar while it is doing the copy. but I found when doing the full copy it was taking about 10 - 20 seconds.

Comment: one thing you could do for a full copy is see if the number of selected rows is the same as the number of rows in the datasource and just copy the entire datasource to the second one and clear the first datasource rather than copying individual rows.

Comment: nice suggestion to copy all to datasource to the destinationgrid and clear.if some record is not selected how to do it .any suggestion or workaround to speed up transferring record

Comment: an alternative is to do this via some sort of server side technology and just pass the id's back for the rows moving and refresh that way rather than trying to do all the manipulation on the client side. I assume you will be saving this back to some form of database so probably best to do it there.